# Injecting custom env-entry values into EJBs on WildFly

Tags: jakarta-ee, jndi, wildfly-8

I am currently migrating my maven ear from glassfish 4 to wildfly 8.2. The problem i am facing right now is accessing the custom `env-entry` values specified in the ejb-jar.xml. In my ejb package i have in the META-INF folder following file:

ejb-jar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         version = "3.1"
         xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd">
    <enterprise-beans>
        <session>
            <ejb-name>HelloWorldEJB</ejb-name>
            <env-entry>
                <description>Some description</description>
                <env-entry-name>HelloWorld</env-entry-name>
                <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
                <env-entry-value>testvalue</env-entry-value>
            </env-entry>
        </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

And i inject the property in my ejb like that:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class HelloWorldEJB {

    @Resource(name = "HelloWorld")
    private String helloWorld;

}
```

Anybody an idea?